# Python Search and Replace is duplicating replace string?

Tags: python, replace

I have the following code that's looping through files in a folder and doing a simple search and replace, and then outputs the results to a different folder. What I am noticing is that the replace string seems to be getting applied twice.

For example:

`Search string: foo`

`Replace string: foo bar`

`Result: foo bar bar`

Here is my code. I'm sure the problem is obvious, but I just can't put my finger on it.

```
def SearchReplace(directory, search, replace, filePattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            outfile = os.path.join(outputdir, filename)
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(search, replace)
            with open(outfile, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
SearchReplace(inputdir, searchstr, replacestr, ext)
```

NOTE: if I do not output the results to a separate folder, the search/replace performs as expected. Meaning, the code below works fine (modifies input file in same folder):

```
def SearchReplace(directory, search, replace, filePattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(search, replace)
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
SearchReplace(inputdir, searchstr, replacestr, ext)
```

However, I need to output the results to a separate folder.

Comment: Um, what was the original text? If it was `foo bar` in the beginning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your output folder is included in the input search pattern, so the replacement is made once on the input file, then again on the output file.

Comment: Expanding on this:  If `outputdir` is `"C:\stuff\modified"` and `inputdir` is `"C:\stuff"`, then your code first visits `"C:\stuff"` writes to `"C:\stuff\modified"`, and then visits `"C:\stuff\modified"` and writes to `"C:\stuff\modified"`.

Comment: Ahh...foiled by the indent. <Python noob hangs head in shame>.  Thanks, Mark! :)

Comment: One way to avoid this is to add `if outputdir==path: continue` just below your outer loop.

Comment: @keith:  I'm not sure I understand.  I don't think Mark Byers was addressing indentation.  Where is indentation causing this issue?

Comment: I just moved (left-indent, or whatever you call it) this code outside the for loop: `with open(outfile, "w") as f:` See above.

Comment: @Keith: I don't think that's the correct way to solve the problem. That will result in only one file being handled. A better solution is to not have the output directory inside the input directory, or else to filter it as Steven showed.

Comment: Ahh..yes, you are correct. I had a false positive as I was only testing with one file. I will need to update my code. Thanks Mark and Steven!

Comment: I ended up using Steven's suggestion: `if outputdir==path: continue`, as I need to have the output folder within the input directory. Thanks again all!